# Porting eBubble.js to google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to port Mike Williams eBubble.js to API v3, got most it if done but got stumped on one part.  You can see my work in progress here: http://gvs.megarry.com/test.html

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

EBubble.prototype.openOnMarker = function(marker,html) {
    var vx = marker.getIcon().iconAnchor.x - marker.getIcon().infoWindowAnchor.x;
    var vy = marker.getIcon().iconAnchor.y - marker.getIcon().infoWindowAnchor.y;
    this.openOnMap(marker.getPoint(), html, new google.maps.Point(vx,vy));
}
```

Does this work in API v3?  Inspecting the DOM in firebug does show the function `getIcon()`

Comment: I have the task as you have.you should change marker.getPoint() to marker.getPosition(). but for the rest I don't have any idea.

Comment: @Dennis did you come up with a working solution for v3? It would be great if you could answer your own question then.